# SDK for MediaTek

Tags: iphone

How can we get (paying) the SDK for MediaTek 6223/6225/6235?

Regards,

Carlos Paz
lorgot at hotmail dot com

Comment: Have you tried to contact MediaTek at http://www.mediatek.com ?

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for replying.

I have been trying for a long time.
These days they replied once and now I'm trying them to follow talking to me.

Could you help me?


Regards,

Carlos

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.vogins.com/vre_developer_en.html
The SDK is in chinese .Just in case you get an English version .let me know :)